# PHP - passing functions return to another function

Tags: php, function, return

I have a PHP function that returns something:

```
function myfunction() {
   $array = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');

   foreach($array as $i) {
     echo $i;
   }
}
```

And another function where I want to pass return values from the function above:

```
function myfunction2() {
   //how to send myfunction()'s output here? I mean:
   //echo 'onetwothreefour';
   return 'something additional';
}
```

I guess it will look something like `myfunction2(myfunction)` but I don't know PHP too much and I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Using return in  a foreach does'nt sound right. Because it will return once and exit the function, so it will not get to the next array item.

Comment: I don't understand exactly your question. Can you be more clear?

Comment: What should the output be ? `onetwothreefoursomething additional` ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you just need

```
return myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

`myfunction` will always return `"one"`. Nothing else. Please revise the behaviour of [`return`](http://php.net/return)

After that, if you still want the return value of one function inside another, just call it.

```
function myfunction2() {
    $val = myfunction();
    return "something else";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunction2() {

  $myvariable=myfunction();
  //$myvar now has the output of myfunction()

  //You might want to do something else here

 return 'something additional';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function myfunction() {
   $array = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
   $concat = '';
   foreach($array as $i) {
     $concat .= $i;
   }
   return $concat;
}

function myfunction2() {
   return myfunction() . "something else";
}
```

this will return `onetwothreefoursomthing else`

Working example here http://codepad.org/tjfYX1Ak