# What is the purpose of second return function here?

Tags: php, functional-programming

This example taken from phptherightway's functional programming page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Creates an anonymous filter function accepting items > $min
 *
 * Returns a single filter out of a family of "greater than n" filters
 */
function criteria_greater_than($min)
{
    return function($item) use ($min) {
        return $item > $min;
    };
}

$input = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

// Use array_filter on a input with a selected filter function
$output = array_filter($input, criteria_greater_than(3));

print_r($output); // items > 3
```

What is the purpose of having `return function()` ?

I just wrote this and it does the same thing.

```
array_filter($input, function($input) use ($min) {
    return $input > $min;
}); // items > 3
```

Even if I appoint this callback to a function, the secondary function seems unnecessary.

Did I overlook something or does it have a different purpose?

Comment: second return is for the returned function

Comment: `return function()` creates a function, and returns a reference to it to the calling scope. That'd be a returned up to array_filter, which uses that reference to call this newly created function anytime it needs to do its comparison operations.

Comment: It returns a closure ( look it up: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php ), this is actually a pretty neat way of doing this. It's mainly very reusable. If the internal code needs to be changed in the closure, you'd only have to do it in the function. It's also very readable, you actually read "filter array where criteria is greater then 3". I like it!

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230236/php-passing-functions-return-to-another-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely necessary for `criteria_greater_than` to return the value you want to return. Eg. for a function to return the value 5:

```
function get_5() {
    return 5;
}
```

You use it like `$var = get_5();`, but if you were setting it to a constant you would just do `$var = 5;` or `call_my_function(5)`. Notice you need to use `return` in order to return anything in a function. Now consider this function:

```
function get_fx($x)
{
    return function () use ($x)
           {
               return $x;
           };
}

$v5 = get_fx(5);
$v6 = get_fx(6);
```

What are `$v5` and `$v6`?.. Well they are functions, because thats what they returned. In fact `$v5() == get_5()` is true, but $6() == get_5() is false, because `get_fx` return different functions (closures) dependent on the arguments passed.

If you were to skip the first `return` you wouldn't get anything from the first function.. eg. $v5 and $v6 wouldn't have anything assigned. If you skipped the second `return` in the returned function they wouldn't return anything when called, ie. `$v5()` wouldn't return 5 and `$v6()` wouldn't return 6.

Answer (score 0):

Second param of `array_filter` is `callback`. You can specify it inside `array_filter` as `anonymous function` or specify name of the function. Inside of `anonymous function` you do the filtering, that's why `return` used. The second one return is to use anonymous function as a callback at `array_filter` it returns the reference on this function.

Comment: "The second one return is to use anonymous function as a callback at array_filter it returns the reference on this function." Can you elaborate this a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Second function allows you to pass not only callback to array_filter but callback and filtration context ($min) at once. It is convinient way to reuse code.